# Adding more than one links for a branch/pull request to an User Story in Azure Devops

Tags: azure, azure-devops, branch, pull-request, azure-repos

In Azure Devops "User Story View" I am able to create a branch for specific story. I am using a link from this panel:

[image]

I am currently working not only with one repository for this story but with couple of them. How can I create another branch/pull request in another repo and link it to this story?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create it from this menu item:

[image]